# Hyperledger Fabric: Modifying the ledger outside the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Isn't it possible for someone to tamper with the ledger by writing directly to the [ledgersData](https://blockchain-fabric.blogspot.com/2019/02/hyperledger-fabric-ledger-backup-and.html) folder on their peer? Wouldn't that cause all sorts of problems such as ledger getting out of sync between nodes? How do you protect against that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the point of having distributed ledgers. The ledgerData mustn't be tampered with, If one does tamper the data, their transactions will be deemed invalid here on and cannot participate in the network.

The peer is responsible to maintain the locally held ledger. The orderer ensures the same in an endorsement response by the read-set values. The peer's endorsement is only accounted for if they match across other responses.

I believe your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717211/hyperledger-fabric-getting-endorsement-from-one-vs-multiple-peers) is also related to a similar issue, hope I was helpful.

Comment: "If one does tamper the data, their transactions will be deemed invalid". this needs explanation. How? HL fabric does not come with any consensus protocol running on peer nodes themselves. Its consensus protocol only ensures that transactions happening through the normal flow of chaincode execution will end up in consistent state. And the scenario postulated here is when an attacker bypasses the chaincode and directly writes data to the ledger.

Comment: @morpheus The chaincode is executed against the current state database to produce transaction results including a response value, read set, and write set (i.e. key/value pairs representing an asset to create or update).

The read set [representing current world state] must be same for all the peer. If one does tamper with the ledger, this read set will change. This is how the response is invalidated.

The write set contains new values to the world state. This value depends on the current state as well. So, consequently, write set will also mismatch with other peers.

Comment: read https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html for an explanation with example/