# Hyperledger Fabric: Getting endorsement from one vs. multiple peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Given the fact that all peers are running the same chaincode and have same ledger, does it make any difference whether one or multiple peers are chosen for endorsement? Isn't getting endorsement from multiple peers redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger fabric uses order-execute model by separating the transaction flow into three steps:

- execute a transaction and check its correctness, thereby endorsing it,
- order transactions via a (pluggable) consensus protocol, and
- validate transactions against an application-specific endorsement policy before committing them to the ledger.

When a peer gets a transaction, it executes transactions against the current state data held by it to simulate the transaction.

The most probable reason for multiple peer endorsement is to ensure concurrent states across peers upon execution of the transaction and ensuring correct transaction execution, This is necessary to ensure data that was read during chaincode execution has not changed, and therefore the execution results are still valid and can be committed to the ledger state database.